# VLOOKUP text inside a string

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vlookup

I have a column `DeviceName` in `Sheet1` and it contains data like `RTRNY653, SWNY653, ...` In `Sheet2` I have a column `InterfaceName` and it contains interface names and at the end the device name is listed too `FA_01_RTRNY653, FA_12_SWNY653, ...`

The standard formula to get the `QoSID` linked to the `DeviceName` would be `=VLOOKUP(DeviceName;Sheet2!InterfaceName;2;0)`, but because `InterfaceName` contains more text, I'm stuck ...

Question: How can I create a VLOOKUP function that uses the `DeviceName` from `Sheet1`, looks it up in the `InterfaceName` on `Sheet2` and gets me column `QoSID` from `Sheet2`.

**Example data**

```
Sheet1
DeviceName
-----------
RTRNY653
SWNY653
RTRWS215
RTRCH888

Sheet2
InterfaceName     | QoSID
--------------------------
FA_01_RTRNY653    |   1
FA_12_SWNY653     |   2
S_00_RTRWS215     |   1
S_01_RTRWS215     |   3
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make use of wildcards like this:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&DeviceName&"*";Sheet2!InterfaceName:QoSID;2;0)
```

Also, the reference table has to be two columns :)

Comment: Thanks, will check as soon as I get to work. But I think Wildcards was what I was looking for :)

Comment: Excellent! Wildcards, something I need to remember!

Comment: Is there a similar application of this where the value to be looked up isn't a substring and instead the substring exists within the vlookup table? I.e. you have a table of subtrings with their corresponding look-up value, and you want to lookup a larger string to which the value to be looked up is one of many options that may exist within the value to be looked up?

Comment: @Xzila Yea, but I don't think the solution will be as easy as the above one. I'd use an array formula using index, search/find, row and min. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: I used `=IFERROR(INDEX({Col1_From_Table_of_SubStrings},MATCH(TRUE,ArrayFormula(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({Col2_From_Table_of_SubStrings},{ValueToSearchForSubStringsWithin}))),0)),"#NoSubStrings!")` but I'm still interested in your solution! I love to learn new or better ways of doing things.

Comment: Oh mine is a bit longer and slower actually `=IFERROR(INDEX({Col1_From_Table_of_SubStrings},MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({Col2_From_Table_of_SubStrings},{ValueToSearchForSubStringsWithin})),ROW({Col1_From_Table_of_SubStrings})))),"#NoSubStrings!")`. The only upside is that it can give multiple matches if you use `SMALL`/`LARGE` instead of `MIN` (e.g. using `SMALL({...}, N)` and having a sequence of numbers for multiple values of N.